# Unicode representation of an object back into an object (in python)

Tags: python, unicode, urlparse, python-object

*FYI - this is program uses Django but I am **NOT** tagging it as such because it is not a django problem. The django code is here for context*

**~~The Background~~**

I uncovered a bug that I had in a program. In short, I am using `urlparse.urlparse` to get information from a given URI and save it to a database.

The goal is to do something like this:

```
url = urlparse.urlparse('http://somedomain.com/yada/yada')
some_instance = Domain(address=url.netloc)
```

**~~The Problem~~**

The problem is that because of a mistake in coding, the database is full of the `urlparse` object. Therefore, when recalling the instance from the database the result is a unicode string:

```
some_instance = Domain.objects.get(pk=XX)
some_instance.address
>>> u"ParseResult(scheme=u'http', netloc=u'www.somedomain.com', path=u'/', params='', query=u'_vsrefdom=googleppc', fragment='')"
```

Oops.

**~~The Question~~**

Clearly I need to go back and fix a number of records. What I am curious to know is if there is a good pythonic way to restore a unicode representation of an object (not the actual `.__unicode__()` return) back into the object itself.

Thoughts?

I have looked around a bit on Google and StackOverflow, problem is any search I have come across deals with the output of the `.__unicode__()` and not the whole representation itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you can use `eval`; even though generally frowned upon, it is acceptable in this case.

```
>>> from urlparse import ParseResult
>>> s = u"ParseResult(scheme=u'http', netloc=u'www.somedomain.com', path=u'/', params='', query=u'_vsrefdom=googleppc', fragment='')"
>>> pr = eval(s)
>>> pr.scheme, pr.netloc
(u'http', u'www.somedomain.com')
```

Comment: Beautiful. That's what I needed. Thanks. (Will mark as answer when enough time passes)